# Rspec stub doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have following spec to test controller method:

```
context "#create" do
  it "should redirect when model is valid" do
    User.stub!(:valid?).and_return(true)
    post :create, :user => FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user)
    response.should redirect_to("/")
  end
  it "should render new template when model is invalid" do
    User.stub!(:valid?).and_return(false)
    post :create, :user => FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user)
    response.should render_template(:new)
  end
end
```

And controller itself:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    redirect_to "/", :notice => "User created"
  else
    render "new"
  end
end
```

Pretty much straightforward code, but somehow `stub!` method just doesn't really stubs, so second spec fails with `expecting <"new"> but rendering with <"">`. It just redirects like if `valid?` returned true.

I'm quite new to Rails world. What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When saving an object, Rails calls `valid?` on an instance of a class. But you've stubbed `valid?` on the *class itself*. That won't work.

What you want to do here is stub `save` on the *instance* of User that is being saved, e.g.

`User.stub(:new) { mock_model(User, :save => true) }`

`@user = User.new` # @user is now a mock object

`@user.save` # mock object returns `true`

For the other example:

`User.stub(:new) { mock_model(User, :save => false) }`

`@user = User.new` # again, @user is a mock

`@user.save` # mock object returns `false`

Comment: OMG Thanks for instance tip! That was the problem. Although i think it would be better to stub low-level methods, like `valid?`. This way I will be able to refactor action from say `save` to `build` & `create` without breaking functionality & tests. This is not the case in this situation, of course. Right now I've solved it by attaching stub to all instances of User `User.any_instance.stub(:valid?).and_return(true)`. But your hint with instance and class is what I missed in general.

Comment: As far as stubbing `valid?` instead of `save`, I'd argue the exact opposite :) Your point about refactoring is a good one, but we can turn that right around -- what if ActiveRecord is refactored, and `save` no longer calls `valid?` under the hood? Now your tests break because of the internal implementation of a library that you don't control.

Comment: Well we hardly will switch ActiveRecord in Production before we test it in Dev/Test, isn't it? :) And if we will in Development/Test, then it will be obvious, since tests will fail from this point. So we can always relate to changelog or something to figure out reason. It is much likely from my perspective that application classes will be refactored than core classes.

Comment: @zetetic : This has been a quite older thread, had a curious question about is there any way to reset the stub itself? There should be a way to return different values in different test cases.